# How to call a javascript method from aspx.cs

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to call a method hello() in javascript from aspx.cs ( c# ) when a listbox1 item is selected.Using this code to do it but not working

```
protected void ListBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "whatiskey","hello();", true); 
    }
```

---

```
    function hello() {
alert("hiiiii");
 var arr = ["<%=myvalue %>"];


            }
```

Comment: Not working means? are you getting any error message

Comment: No error , just the method not executed

Comment: try : Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript( GetType(), "whatiskey", "hello();", true);

Comment: @Zaki not working , does the key parameter has to do something with it as I have no key defined at javascript its just a method

Comment: try   ClientManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "whatiskey","javascript:hello();", true); and also put an alert on the first line of the method. And also check console for any error

Comment: Not working @SatyakiChatterjee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
Response.Write("<script>hello();</script>");
```

**EDIT**

if all you wanna do is call a javascript on selection of an item, you can use onchange attribute as follows -

```
<asp:ListBox onchange="hello();" ID="ListBox1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>

    </asp:ListBox>
    <script>
        function hello() {
            alert("hello");
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: have you set EnableAutoPostBack property of ListBox to true ?

Answer (score 2):

Setting "AutoPostBack" property of ListBox to "true" and using `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "whatiskey", "hello();", true);` worked for me

Comment: Sorry for marking it unanswered , the page is being refreshed but the method is not being called

Comment: @phpnet Can you provide "hello" method declaration, please? Where is it declared?

Comment: @phpnet Javascript is enabled in browser? That still works fine for me

Comment: Yes it is , thank you for your reply I think there is some other problem at my side